# Que una variable date solo almacene año y mes

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Experiencia con los siguientes parametros:

```
Schema::create('experiencias', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('puesto');
        $table->string('funcion_realizada');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector_empresa');
        $table->date('mes_anyo_inicio');
        $table->date('mes_anyo_fin');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y tengo este formulario para insertar una nueva fila:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Introduzca su experiencia laboral</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="nueva_experiencia" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="puesto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Puesto en el que trabajó</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="puesto" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('puesto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="puesto" value="{{ old('puesto') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if($errors->has('puesto'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('puesto') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="funcion_realizada" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Función realizada</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="funcion_realizada" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('funcion_realizada') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="funcion_realizada" value="{{ old('funcion_realizada') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if($errors->has('funcion_realizada'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('funcion_realizada') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="empresa" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Empresa para la que trabajó</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="empresa" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('empresa') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="empresa" value="{{ old('empresa') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if($errors->has('empresa'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('empresa') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sector_empresa" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Sector en el que trabajó</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="sector_empresa" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('sector_empresa') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="sector_empresa" value="{{ old('sector_empresa') }}" required autofocus>
                                    @foreach($sectores as $sector)
                                        <option value="{{$sector->nombre}}">{{$sector->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('sector_empresa'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('sector_empresa') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="mes_anyo_inicio" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha en la que empezó su trabajo</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="mes_anyo_inicio" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('mes_anyo_inicio') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="mes_anyo_inicio" value="{{ old('mes_anyo_inicio') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if($errors->has('mes_anyo_inicio'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('mes_anyo_inicio') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="mes_anyo_fin" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha en la que acabó su trabajo</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="mes_anyo_fin" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('mes_anyo_fin') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="mes_anyo_fin" value="{{ old('mes_anyo_fin') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if($errors->has('mes_anyo_fin'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('mes_anyo_fin') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}"/>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Guardar Experiencia
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

La historia son las variables `mes_anyo_inicio` y `mes_anyo_fin`, las cuales son variables tipo fecha, pero quiero que mi formulario solo almacenen el mes y el año.
¿Como consigo eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes cambiar el tipo del input de `date` a `month`

```
<input id="month" type="month" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" />
```

El pattern es para que los navegadores que aún no implementan el tipo month y degradan a input tipo text tengan un pattern de entrada (AAAA-MM).

Actualmente (Junio 2018) sólo chrome, opera y edge lo soportan. 
Hay varias formas sugeridas de implementar un degradado aceptable en:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month

copio debajo el ejemplo de `input` `month` que se transforma en dos `select`s

(original https://jsfiddle.net/p410hdub/)

```js
// define variables
var nativePicker = document.querySelector('.nativeDatePicker');
var fallbackPicker = document.querySelector('.fallbackDatePicker');
var fallbackLabel = document.querySelector('.fallbackLabel');

var yearSelect = document.querySelector('#year');
var monthSelect = document.querySelector('#month');

// hide fallback initially
fallbackPicker.style.display = 'none';
fallbackLabel.style.display = 'none';

// test whether a new date input falls back to a text input or not
var test = document.createElement('input');
test.type = 'month';
// if it does, run the code inside the if() {} block
if(test.type === 'text') {
  // hide the native picker and show the fallback
  nativePicker.style.display = 'none';
  fallbackPicker.style.display = 'block';
  fallbackLabel.style.display = 'block';

  // populate the years dynamically
  // (the months are always the same, therefore hardcoded)
  populateYears();
}

function populateYears() {
  // get the current year as a number
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  // Make this year, and the 100 years before it available in the year <select>
  for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = year-i;
    yearSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 100px;
}

input + span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input:invalid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input:valid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month -->

<form>
  <div class="nativeDatePicker">
    <label for="month-visit">En qué mes nos visitará?</label>
    <input type="month" id="month-visit" name="month-visit">
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <p class="fallbackLabel">En qué mes nos visitará?</p>
  <div class="fallbackDatePicker">
    <div>
      <span>
        <label for="month">Mes:</label>
        <select id="month" name="month">
          <option selected>Enero</option>
          <option>Febrero</option>
          <option>Marzo</option>
          <option>Abril</option>
          <option>Mayo</option>
          <option>Junio</option>
          <option>Julio</option>
          <option>Agosto</option>
          <option>Septiembre</option>
          <option>Octubre</option>
          <option>Noviembre</option>
          <option>Diciembre</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span>
        <label for="year">Año:</label>
        <select id="year" name="year">
        </select>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Otra opción es usar [jQuery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) limitando a año y mes como en este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209104/1423096

Comment: Gracias. Estoy viendo que para la poquita cosa que queria hacer hay que montar tela, pues tendria que crear 2 variables, una para el mes y otra para el año.

Answer (score 0):

Si defines las columnas *mes_anyo_inicio* y *mes_anyo_fin* como date en la base de datos, esta va a esperar que lo introduzcas en ese formato. Aunque captures la request y modifiques esos valores, posiblemente te de error igualmente.

La forma más simple y rápida que tienes de hacer esto, es declararlos como string y en la request capturar los dos campos, quedarte solo con el mes y el año e insertarlo así.